# What does it mean to "lock on" to a DME ground station?

Tags: avionics, dme

I was just reading about the working of the DME the other day and then I read a para which said:

> The aircraft interrogator "locks on" to the DME ground station once it
>   recognizes a particular pulse sequence having the same spacing as the
>   original interrogation sequence

Can anybody please elaborate on the above statement? I just want to know what is "lock on" and how does an aircraft interrogator lock on to a DME ground station?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How does an airborne DME unit differentiate itself?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/73837/how-does-an-airborne-dme-unit-differentiate-itself)

Answer (score 4):

"Lock-on" just refers to a unit receiving multiple different response signals in response to its interrogation broadcasts, scanning for the signal it's looking for, and when it finds the signal who's encoding matches its channel selection, it starts to process that signal and ignores all others.  It's locked on to that signal.

Answer (score 0):

The ground station transmits responses to interrogations
from other aircraft and randomly timed signals that look
just like responses, so an aircraft has to pick responses to
its transmissions out of all the other signals that look
like they could be. The way it's done is by looking at the
ground station transmissions for a while trying to find a
time after its interrogations where there's usually a
response. (Not all interrogations get responses.) Once the
time slot is found the aircraft can calculate the distance
to the ground station and only has to track the changes in
the distance from then on. It reduces its interrogation rate in
accordance with its lighter workload and is locked on.